# Get the webpage tittle and paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me i want generate JavaScript or macro to get the webpage tittle, paragraph text, images data in single sheet with the component used.

Comment: try to include some more details..
HTML Markup, WebSite address, jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1):

For title:

```
document.title
```

For paragraphs:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p") //this will give you array of all p tags in page
```

For images:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` like so:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

Or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")
```

This works with other tags, such as `input`, `div` etc.

To get the title simply use:

```
document.title
```